# What do the white circle and black arrow on the airport chart mean? (VOR identifier and frequency written)

Tags: aeronautical-charts, vor, symbology

What do the white circle and black arrow on the airport chart mean? (VOR identifier and frequency written) There are 2 on the chart. Also, is there a document where I can find the meanings of the symbols on the airport chart? The document is from Turkey AIP.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that the circle and black arrow (with the VOR identifier and frequency) noted on the airport diagram in your question represents
a "VOR Aerodrome Checkpoint Marking" ([Source: ICAO-Annex-14-Volume-1-Aerodrome-Design-and-Operations](https://www.pilot18.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Pilot18.com-ICAO-Annex-14-Volume-1-Aerodrome-Design-and-Operations.pdf)). You can scroll from the Source document to the pages and figures shown in the images below for additional information:

*(highlighting is mine)*

[image]

[image]

[image]